# Can I get all venue database from foursquare?

Tags: database, foursquare

Can I get all venue database from foursquare?

I want develop program what can see all venue in world map.

Then I need all venue database.

Comment: Have you tried the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com/)? How far did you get?

Comment: I need all venue in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, and should not get all the venues - The usage policy by Foursquare does not allow this.

A similar question can be found here: [Foursquare API: Getting an exhaustive list of venues in a given area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10900896/foursquare-api-getting-an-exhaustive-list-of-venues-in-a-given-area)

Unless you want to copy foursquare server with a good head start by stealing their data (:|), you do not really need *all* their venues (see the other question).

Comment: Thanks. Had been very helpful^^.